# How do I programmatically update the Resque schedule?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

So I'm looking into adding some functionality in my app which will allow users to schedule certain tasks. A brief search brought Resque and Resque-Scheduler to my attention. However, I'm wondering if it will let me change scheduled tasks on the fly. From what I've seen, the scheduler only loads from a config file. Is there some way to make this work, or am I pursuing the wrong track?

Answer (score 1):

Not really `config` is not the only way to schedule a task in `resque` using `resque-scheduler`

`config` is generally used for recurring task something like `cron-tab` do in your case

but in your case it wont work here how you can programmatically schedule your task using resque-scheduler

```
Resque.enqueue_in(5.days, SomeJob) # run a job in 5 days
```

or

```
Resque.enqueue_at(5.days.from_now, SomeJob) # run SomeJob at a specific time
```

You can also remove them if you want

```
Resque.remove_delayed
```

You can find completed guide of it in **resque-scheduler** [README](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler)

Hope this help

Comment: I'm looking to add recurring tasks on the fly is the thing though. I did just notice, however, that in their example configuration for the rake task you can set the schedule to be dynamic. I'll see how that works out.

Comment: @SlipperyJohn Yes you can but that is only available in resque-scheduler latest version I'm not sure of which version older version is it not anyway I just missed that thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the schedule dynamically.

From the repo readme (https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler)

> Dynamic schedules allow for greater flexibility than static schedules as they can be set, unset or changed without having to restart resque-scheduler. You can specify, if the schedule must survive a resque-scheduler restart or not.

[Note that at the time of this writing, the approach of setting "Resque:Scheduler.dynamic = true" in your Rakefile is not working. Instead, use the option of setting an env variable (DYNAMIC_SCHEDULE)]